# Spring JPA. Call @ManyToMany ONLY and not the whole object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, dao

Suppose I have something like this:

```
   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinTable(name = "assigned_tasks", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "task_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
   private Set<Task> assignedTasksDoer = new HashSet<>();
```

in my "User" entity class.

When I fetch the user it brings me all the details. And that's great. No errors whatsoever.
But how can I break it apart in pieces, so for example, when I want to fetch ONLY the "assigned_tasks" OF the User I can just fetch it from a different controller other than the UserController, i.e. the AssignedTasksController?

I'm willing to provide more details if anyone is interested.

Please help me as I am starting this Object Oriented approach!! Yes, working with jpa, entities, DAOs and repositories is great, while letting Spring take care of everything under the hood, is great, but are there limitations to it? Can I completely avoid writing sql queries and prepares statements or other cases where I will have to resort to it?

TL;DR: The User entity has other fields too. I want make a controller route that only fetches the assigned tasks of the user, and not the whole object everytime. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you share the whole entities

Comment: I think this query can fetch the tasks for specific user

    entityManager.createQuery("Select distinct t from Task t join t.users u where u.id = :uid")

Comment: It will more clear your question if you add an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using Spring Data JPA. In that case you most likely already have something like a `UserRepository extends JpaRepositry<User, Long>` (assuming the primary key is a Long).

Just create a `TaskRepository extends JpaRepository<Task, Long>` and add the following method: `List<Task> findAllByUserId(Long userId);` to that interface. This assumes that `Task` has a field `User user` and the primary field of `User` is called `id` (hence the "byUserId").

See [Spring Data JPA, Query Creation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) for more details on how to create queries using a Spring Data repository.

If you need more control, you can also take a look at the `@Query` annotation in the same documentation.

Comment: I know what you're saying. I have used both @query and I already a taskrepository.

Comment: In my case though, I dont want to fetch the assigned tasks of each task, but instead i want to fetch the assigned tasks just by itself.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve then. What exactly do you mean with "only fetches the assigned tasks of the user" if not fetching the collection of Tasks assigned to a user?

Comment: You are right I forgot to explain it very well. Sorry for causing misunderstanding. I can already fetch the tasks for each user. But each user has both tasks and assigned tasks. assigned to them by other users. In the db, I made it so the assigned tasks table is a join table that joins the corresponding task with the corresponding user. I can put the assignedtasks list in the user model and then fetch works fine, but unfortunately it also fetches all the user details, but I only want to fetch the user's asssigned tasks and not the other fields too... ...

Comment: I am currently working on attempting a solution like the one you proposed... If it works I will accept your answer as correct.

Comment: 'I only want to fetch the user's asssigned tasks and not the other fields too...' is the part that confuses me, how is that different than selecting assigned tasks by user id? If you want to select assigned tasks only, and **no other information**, why do they need to come packaged in a `User` object? In any case, if you're looking for fetching some entity properties and not others, [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-graph) is what you're after